# (Py-cord) Как узнать, есть ли у пользователя права администратора

Tags: python, бот, pycord

Нужно узнать, есть ли у пользователя права администратора. Есть объект `discord.User`. Читал документацию, никак не могу найти
P.S. - именно Py-cord, не discord.py